# MySQL/MariaDB MAX on DATETIME anomaly in correlated subquery

Tags: mysql, datetime, max, mariadb

Why behavior of MAX in MariaDB is different when the fractional seconds is introduced when using correlated subquery (grouping by specific column)?

I tried creating below table:

```
create table test(id bigint, pipe_no char(5), start_time datetime(6), value_date datetime);

insert into test(id, pipe_no, start_time, value_date) values (1, 'p1', '2016-9-28 01:00:00.111111', '2016-9-30 01:00:00.111111');
insert into test(id, pipe_no, start_time, value_date) values (2, 'p2', '2016-9-28 01:00:00.222222', '2016-9-30 01:00:00.111111');
insert into test(id, pipe_no, start_time, value_date) values (3, 'p3', '2016-9-28 01:00:00.333333', '2016-9-30 01:00:00.111111');
insert into test(id, pipe_no, start_time, value_date) values (4, 'p1', '2016-9-28 01:00:01.111111', '2016-9-29 01:00:00.111111');
insert into test(id, pipe_no, start_time, value_date) values (5, 'p2', '2016-9-28 01:00:01.222222', '2016-9-29 01:00:00.111111');
insert into test(id, pipe_no, start_time, value_date) values (6, 'p3', '2016-9-28 01:00:01.333333', '2016-9-29 01:00:00.111111');
insert into test(id, pipe_no, start_time, value_date) values (7, 'p1', '2016-9-28 01:00:02.111111', '2016-9-28 01:00:00.111111');
insert into test(id, pipe_no, start_time, value_date) values (8, 'p2', '2016-9-28 01:00:02.222222', '2016-9-28 01:00:00.111111');
insert into test(id, pipe_no, start_time, value_date) values (9, 'p3', '2016-9-28 01:00:02.333333', '2016-9-28 01:00:00.111111');
```

Applying MAX to start_time and value_date will give different result. Note that *start_time* is *datetime(6)* while *value_date* is *datetime*.

```
select * from test this 
      where this.start_time = (
      select max(start_time) from test that 
             where that.pipe_no = this.pipe_no);

select * from test this 
      where this.value_date = (
      select max(value_date) from test that 
             where that.pipe_no = this.pipe_no);
```

The first query somewhat didn't return any result. 
Expected result should be this [image: start_time]

The second result by value_date is as expected [image: value_date]

Doing cast to char will give correct result

```
... this.start_time = (select max(cast(start_time as char)) ...;
```

Or using greater than '>'

```
... this.start_time > (select max(start_time) ...;
```

Or use specific grouping like

```
select * from test this 
      where this.pipe_no = 'p1' and this.start_time = (
      select max(start_time) from test that 
            where that.pipe_no = 'p1');
```

All will give result expected from MAX.

Running max(start_time) itself will return result including the fractional seconds.

```
select max(start_time) from test where pipe_no='p1'
```

> 2016-09-28 01:00:02.111111

Can someone point out how the MAX works with fractional seconds within correlated subquery? Already run through some documentation but haven't found the part that explains this relationship. Looks like the fractional seconds is truncated when MAX is applied within this context.

Thank you in advance.

[EDIT] I reversed the order of value_date against the start_time so the expected result can be easily differentiated, also modified the title to avoid confusion with terms "grouping by". And sorry for the image, I didn't have reputation I need to show the inline image, so I showed as link instead.

Comment: You say "grouping by", but I see no `GROUP BY`.

Comment: They give "different result" -- Please show what you get and which one is "correct".

Comment: Which version of MariaDB are you using?

Comment: I refer to grouping by certain column (in this case "pipe_no") using subqueries. I am using MariaDB version 10.1.13 and RazorSQL for the GUI. Added the expected result on the question.

Comment: Maybe you can use UNIX_TIMESTAMP and over that use MAX

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. For practical reason I use '>' over MAX (though it looks terribly wrong conceptually since there should be nothing greater than max). Just wonder if this behavior does comply with SQL requirement.